# Is there a term for half working while traveling?

Tags: vacation, travel

I will be going on an extended vacation, but I will be working for half the time. Kind of like half digital nomad, half on PTO.

Is there a term for this? I'm supposed to mark my calendar when I'm on vacation, but if I put OOO (out of office), it implies that I'm not available.

How do I indicate that I won't be in the office, but I'm still available for work, meetings, etc.

Comment: `"I'm on vacation but will still be working."` That's a bit of an oxymoron. You're either on vacation or you're not. If you plan on working then say `"I'll be out of the office but will be available."` If you don't plan on working then say `"I'll be out of the office and will not be available."`

Comment: Equivalent to stating "Working from home" although it's not exactly home in your case...

Comment: @SolarMike - "remote" fits the bill in my workplace.

Comment: I'm having trouble rectifying: *"I will be working for half the time"* with *"but I'm still available for work, meetings, etc"* Are you only available for specific hours? Or are you *available* any time, but will not be working a full schedule? If you're working "part time" certainly there has to be some mechanism to throttle your work, other than just indicating you're not physically at your desk?

Comment: @joeqwerty to make it clearer, I'm usually a digital nomad, so I work while traveling, but I'm still expected to work 8 hours per day. I'd be expected to show up for all meetings. Now, I'm on PTO, but I don't mind doing some work, since we have unlimited vacation days. I want to indicate that I will be working less than 8h/day and I may not show up for meetings, but I'm still available for urgent tasks.

Comment: @joeqwerty Working vacations are a thing that exists - backpackers are pretty common in European and Commonwealth countries.

Answer (score 4):

This varies case to case, but Outlook's calendar has a *Show as* drop-down value called **Working elsewhere** specifically for this.

If you're using Outlook, you should mark your unavailable time as *Away*, which shows up as a hard-to-miss purple block on your calendar.  The rest of your time could either just be left open or marked as *Working elsewhere*.

[image]

If you aren't using Outlook, use similar calendar functionality to clearly distinguish when you are available and when you are not.